# List products by attribute

Tags: attributes, product-list, ce-1.8.1.0

I have an all.phtml page that I listed all products in here.

This code can get all products info but I want to list by attribute (like search)

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$fancybox = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions')->getThemeOptions('fancybox' );
$grid = MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions')->getThemeOptions('grid' );
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want all products filtered by size? I don't understand the question

Comment: There are 2 attributes for products. I want filtered by (for example) color and size or just color or just size.

Answer (score 1):

The logic inside of the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List is very complex and depends on a lot of classes, e.g. the layer for layered navigation.

`$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` says it already, the collection is loaded, therefore it is not possible to add filters.

I think the easiest way is to hook into `catalog_block_product_list_collection` check whether the action is the one, you want to change (this event is thrown at various places) and then just add the filters with

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attributeName, $value)
```

The alternative is to extend the list class and implement the method `_beforeToHtml` so you can do whatever you want. Then you have to change the block class in your `layout.xml`

Comment: After researched I found this is possible. Used this and worked very well.
$_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('room', '6')->load();